# Pandas keep highest value in every n consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe called `df_initial` with two columns 'a' and 'b' and N rows.

I would like to half the rows number, deleting the row where the value of 'b' is lower.

Thus between row 0 and row 1 I will keep row 1, between row 2 and row 3 I will keep row 3 etc..

This is the result that I would like to obtain:

```
print(df_initial)
         a     b
0     0.04  0.01
1     0.05  0.22
2     0.06  0.34
3     0.07  0.49
4     0.08  0.71
5     0.09  0.09
6     0.10  0.98
7     0.11  0.42
8     0.12  1.32
9     0.13  0.39
10    0.14  0.97
11    0.15  0.05
12    0.16  0.36
13    0.17  1.72
....

print(df_reduced)
         a     b
0     0.05  0.22
1     0.07  0.49
2     0.08  0.71
3     0.10  0.98
4     0.12  1.32
5     0.14  0.97
6     0.17  1.72
....
```

Is there some Pandas function to do this ?

I saw that there is a resample function, `DataFrame.resample()` , but it is valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, so not in this case.

Thanks who will help me

Comment: If you want a random sample you can use `sample()` but what you're describing is pretty specific to your use case so it wouldn't be builtin. I would suggest pulling `b` out as a numpy array and getting the row indices on that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) every two rows (a simple way of doing so is taking the [floor division](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html) of the index) and take the [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) of column `b` to index the dataframe:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(df.index//2).b.idxmax(), :]

    a     b
0  0.05  0.22
1  0.07  0.49
2  0.09  0.71
3  0.11  0.98
4  0.13  1.32
5  0.15  0.97
6  0.17  1.72
```

---

Or using [`DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
df.loc[df.b.rolling(2).max()[1::2].index, :]
```

Comment: Thanks for you contribution. If I would  grouped the rows by 3 or 4 is it just sufficient to divide the index by 3 or 4? Is it right ?

Comment: Yes that'r right, simply take the floor division by as many rows you want to group. You're welcome!

Comment: Thanks, just another question: what happen if sometimes the two rows I am grouping have the same value of 'b' ? Will them kept both ?

Comment: No it will only keep one. GIven two equal values `idxmax` will return the index of the first value.

Answer (score 2):

This is an application for a simple example, you can apply it on your base.

`````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ar = np.array([[1.1, 1.0], [3.3, 0.2], [2.7, 10],[ 5.4, 7], [5.3, 9],[ 1.5, 15]])
df = pd.DataFrame(ar, columns = ['a', 'b'])



for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['b'][i] < df['a'][i]:
        df = df.drop(index = i)
print(df)````
`````